# Angularjs event does not work

Tags: angularjs

```
var  html = "<div ng-click="replay()">Replay</div>"
$("#qSection").html(html);
```

The above code replaces html content in qSection. New html code contains an angular event ng-click. Some existing events in the current angular scope work. But when I replace it with new html contents then new added ng-click not works.

Thanks in advance for proper solution.

Comment: Even the StackOverflow's syntax highlighter gives you a hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If angular event is not working even all the syntax is correct, try using [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

```
var  html = $compile("<div ng-click='replay()'>Replay</div>")($scope);
```

Comment: Here i do this way. var html = $compile("<div ng-click='replay()'>Replay</div>")($scope);
document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML= html; It show following code in html source. <div id="sound" class="ng-binding">[[object HTMLDivElement]]</div>

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, it is worth exploring the sanitize trustAsHtml call :

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

And look at html binding :

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0):

From the code you pasted i can see you are using double quotes inside double quote

You can escape it by using escape character `\`

```
var  html = "<div ng-click=\"replay()\">Replay</div>"
```

or by replacing the inner `"` with `'`

```
var  html = "<div ng-click='replay()'>Replay</div>"
```